# page looks bigger than it should

Tags: css, size, zooming

I've designed a web page with 3 columns arranged like this:

[[left] [content] [right]]

and it is showing like this:

[[left]      [right]] 
        [content]

wehn I ctrd+scroll down, it looks ok, how can I fix this?

the css is:

```
.advert_panel_right{
width:250px;
height:100%;
float:left;
}

.advert_panel_left{
    width:250px;
    height:100%;
    float:right;
}

.content_wraper{
    width:902px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.content{   
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:25px;
}
```

Comment: note that ctrl+scroll down is most browser's shortcut (assuming you're using the mouse wheel) for zoom out.  This means that you're probably zoomed in from the start.  In your browser, go to Tools->Settings->Zoom->Reset or the equivalent setting.

Comment: And you seem to have a fixed specification of 1427 pixels width (250 on each end for the sidebar of the content and 902+25 for the content itself.  If your viewport is any smaller than this (or you have a scrollbar) your content will get pushed to the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.content_wraper{
    width:802px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

does reducing the width of the wrapper helps? i belive it is too large.

Answer (score 2):

EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/GN8RL/

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#left, #content, #right {
  float:left;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

#left, #right {
   width:100px;
}    
#content {
   width:200px;
}
#wrapper {
    width:406px; /* 400 + borders */
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

​

Comment: 410px? I'd say 406 (200 + 100 + 100 + 2x3). Also I don't really think that your answer is relevant. He has problems with his code. You are simply giving an example of a similar, though not exactly the same, case.

Comment: Bram, I am helping the guys. he wanted to do exactly this, i created this example for him, its the 3 column he wanted, simple and clean. I prefer more info than not enough, he now has several options. Please remove your negative comment, I changed the 410 to 406. He also accepted my answer.

Comment: True, I'm sorry. I was to quick in my opinion. I still think, though, that you didn't really answer the question. He is having specific problems with his lay out and his desing (902px width, 25 margin and all that). Your example is plain and simple how to create a three column lay out, but not more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to edit some things (and a typo), but here is a test case. Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/UZfBc/

First of all: float your right panel right, and your left panel left. Get rid of the typo '`content_wraper`'. I assumed that `.content` is the middle div and that `.content_wrapper` is the wrapper.

Your `.content` CANNOT be 100% width, because it will take its parent's value and use that. This means that you have three divs, respectively 250px, 902px (+25px margin) and 250px, which you want to put in one div of 902px. That will never work. Just calculate the size of the .content div: 902 - 250 - 250 - 25 = 377px. Then let it `float: left;`. It will work (as it does in my example)